# Going Over the Div Width?

Tags: html, css

I have a set width for my div in CSS, however, I need something inside of that div to go beyond that width, but can't find a solution. Here's my CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 845px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrapper #content {
    width: 630px;
    float: left;

}

#wrapper #content .post {

    background-image: url('images/black_linen_v2.png');
    padding: 10px;
    color: white; text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;



}

#wrapper #primary {
    color: white;
                }

#wrapper #primary .widget-container {
    color: white; text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
    padding: 10px;

    background-image:url('images/black_linen_v2.png');  
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;

}
```

And here's what I need to go beyond that area:

```
/* This is the ribbon effect */
.ribbon {
     background: #36ff36;
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #36ff36, #21b521);
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#36ff36), to(#21b521));
     padding: 10px 10px;
     margin-left: 50px;
     margin-top: 0;
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;

    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #292929;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #292929;

      /*round the top corners   */
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px ;
     -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px; 
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 10px ;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 10px ;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px ;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px ;


    color: #454545;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #36ff36;
    text-align:center;
}

.arrowl {
     width: 0; height: 0;
     line-height: 0;
     border-left: 20px solid transparent;
     border-top: 10px solid #21b521;
     top: 104%;
     left: 0;
     position: absolute;
}
.arrowr {

     width: 0; height: 0;
     line-height: 0;
     border-right: 20px solid transparent;
     border-top: 10px solid #21b521;
     top: 104%;
     right: 0;
     position: absolute;
}

#footer {position: relative;
    background-image:url('../images/footer.png');
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;} 
/* End of ribbon effect*/
```

The set width conflicts with the ".ribbon", which I need to go beyond that set width.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Posting your HTML would be extremely helpful. Right now, it's almost impossible to help because we don't know your markup. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please post your HTML it it will be a guessing game. However in if you want to create some items which is outside its container, you need to set overflow property on the container.

Answer (score 0):

Set `overflow:visible` on `#wrapper` and use a width that is larger (110%) for `.ribbon` or padding.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the object as fixed position. Then define the position and dimensions. Be sure your parent container has the property `overflow:visible`. your child element will look like this

```
position: fixed;
width:*;
height:*;
```